# Calculating the Big Crunch Time

Tags: cosmology

To calculate the Big Crunch time (time since an expanding universe starts expanding until it collapses), starting from the first Friedmann equation:

$$\left(\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\right)^2 = \frac{8 \pi G}{3} \frac{{\rho_{m,0}}}{a^3} - \frac{K}{a^2}$$

The Universe is initially only matter-dominated with no cosmological constant, and $\rho_{m,0}$ denotes matter density now. I have set up the following integral:

$$\pm \sqrt{\frac{3}{8 \pi G \rho_{m,0}}} \int_0^a \frac{da'}{\left(1/a' -\frac{3K}{8 \pi G \rho_{m,0}}\right)^{1/2}} = t.$$

It has the following solution from Wolfram Alpha:
[image]

where

$$x = a', C = \frac{3K}{8 \pi G \rho_{m,0}}.$$

Please only indicate if I am going in the right direction.

Comment: If you are integrating from $0$ to $a$ you will run into a problem with the $\frac 1x$ part.

Comment: But the limit of it exists, doesn't it?

Comment: Then take the limit and see what answer you get.

Comment: It can be calculated from here: https://www.integral-calculator.com. But if in this procedure I have made a mistake, please indicate that.

Comment: Do we have to assume a zero cosmological constant in the Big crunch scenario? I think we must because if it were there in this case, it would eventually dominate.

Comment: Yes, you must assume $\Lambda=0$ here (and of course, you need to multiply the RHS with $+\sqrt{C}$ and remove the integration constant). What answer did you get when you evaluated this?

Comment: This is what I get: 
$$ 
\frac{\arctan(\frac{1-Ca}{\sqrt{Ca}})}{C^{3/2}} + \frac{\sqrt{a-Ca^2}{C} - \frac{\pi}{2C^{3/2}} = \int_0^a \frac{1}{\sqrt{1/a' - C}} da' 
$$

Comment: Also, in the Big Rip scenerio, the only difference will be $K = -|K|$ in the Friedmann equation. Is that right?

Comment: Please consider solving as much as you can then posting questions (all you have done that far) as you go along.